How to stop Apple Mail from resizing image attachments
I recently had to take a photo of a signed form with my iPhone and I sent it to my Mac and then I sent it to someone in Apple Mail, and unbeknownst to me it made it pixellated and unreadable.
It took two weeks for the party that needed the form to get back to me and tell me that the form was unreadable and they need a new one.
I tried sending another one to them, and since the thread was already started I immediately saw my reply in Apple Mail, and Apple Mail made it pixellated and unreadable.
I was forced to put it in my Sync folder and send them a public link to it, which I dunno if they will accept that as some companies have extreme security where you can't download files from the Internet.
I was going to just switch away from Apple Mail and continue using the web-based mail client.. I'm purposely not telling my email provider because I don't want irrelevant answers that aren't what I'm looking for. In my experience if I introduce anything that could spawn an offshoot away from exactly what I want then I get a ton of responses talking about that other thing I mentioned and not an answer to my question.
But I realized that maybe there's some setting somewhere to stop Apple Mail from doing this to attachments. Because I do like the ding that Apple Mail makes it's very clearly identified as new email where as I do not get this with a web client.
Is there any way to stop Apple Mail from resizing image attachments or changing attachments in any way and just tell it to send attachments as they are?
I am using macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 with Apple Mail 16.0

Great details. What mail provider and setup do you have? Sometimes mail chooses how it works based on account specific settings. Mail Drop is designed to solve this specific problem without worrying about attachment size limits or conversion.

When you attach the image to the message, there should be an option to select the image size with a popup menu containing the following options:

Small
Medium
Large
Actual Size
Original Size

If the original image file size is within the email size limits of your email provider (and the receivers), select 'Original Size'. If it is above the maximum size, choose the option that keeps it as large as possible while being less than the maximum size allowed.

